# Access instance object after using eval

Tags: ruby

I want to create a instance of a class using Eval.

Which works perfect.

But i cant access the object.

```
carreg = "bmw"

Eval(carreg+"= Car.new")  < should evaluate to bmw = Car.new
```

This is fine. Perfect. But when I type in `bmw.inspect` nothing happens. Any ideas ?

**EDIT:**

in irb if i manually do `bmw = Car.new`, i can then access the object... like `bmw.inspect`

Comment: Why are you using `eval` at all for this? Have you considered that you're trying to solve the wrong problem?

Comment: Im new to Ruby. Please bear with me :-)
Well put it this way, im asking the user 
`puts "Reg plate?"`
`carreg = gets.chomp` .
How else can i do this?

Comment: You wouldn't do it all, you'd just say `car = Car.new(carreg)` and let the `Car` know that it is a BWM.

Comment: Ok, how would i then later access the object using `carreg` as a parameter or something... e.g `bmw.a_method`

Comment: You'd just pass the `carreg` around like any other variable. Are you brand new to programming in general?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look up how classes work.

```
class Car
    attr_accessor :carreg

    def display
      puts "CarReg = #{@carreg}"
    end
end


car = Car.new
car.carreg = gets.chomp
car.display
```

Try something like that.

Comment: Thanks for that, but i think i have got what i wanted. My class has a `@@instances << self` in the initialize method. i have now made a method like `def self.instances @@instances end`
and can access details about objects which are of type Car like:
`Car.instances.each{|a| puts "Car Reg: #{a.reg}" if a.reg == regnum }`

Comment: Now, question... is the right way to access propertys etc from objects which are of a particular type? idea is that if a user wants to see propertys of a particular car, they would need to give the Reg number and then the code will use that to find the Object. (p.s i might be overcomplicating things... but just trying to learn)

Comment: And problem why i cant use your code @user2891803 is what if u might have more then one `car`. in your example, there could be multiple carreg and so everytime gets.chomp gets called, it will override the property. this is why i want multiple objects of car

Comment: @@instance is a class variable.This means that only one variable value exists for all objects instantiated from this class. If one object instance changes the value of the variable, that new value will essentially change for all other object instances.
I dont think this will perform how you want, post some code for us to see.